# Benchmarking Oracle User Procedures/Functions

Tags: php, oracle, optimization, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm thinking of a way on how to benchmark an Oracle procedure. My idea is this, put a `logging function` on each `part` of the `procedure` you wish to benchmark. Store the time it entered that part. Then, create another app (using PHP) to compute the difference between each execution.

The PHP app is needed to make it as layman as possible.

This idea wont work though because it is too scattered and obstrusive. If I want to execute the function/procedure multiple times at the same time, the result will be wrong.

Algorithms are fine. Codes is better. The whole app is best. :)

Comment: Why you don't write this log in other table of the database and analyze the result using only SQL queries?

But you would get not really times because of the insert delay...

Comment: Can you phrase your question in the form of a question ? If you are asking how to deal with concurrent runs by different users, you can look at using sys_context('USERENV','SESSIONID') to separate out different session activity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle introduced the DBMS_PROFILER package in 9i.  It does pretty much exactly what you describe, only better.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_profil.htm)

In 11g they introduced the hierarchical profiler, which does something similar but for the entire PL/SQL callstack, not just an individual program unit.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm).

Comment: TKPROF does SQL, the profilers do PL/SQL. Very handy if you use PL/SQL for consuming web services, reading/writing files etc.

Comment: And if you want inspiration for a front-end over the DBMS_PROFILER data, take a look at TOADs charts (bar/pie-charts of where the time is spent, let you drill down into the subsets, and eventually jump out to the source line). There's some real improvements that could be made there (like 'live' jumping around the source) and I'd love to see a simple web-based equivalent tool.